# ASP.NET :-Excel downloaded but not showing data

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am downloading excel from an application developed in ASP.NET and C#.
Its verified that data is coming in excel but when I click on file icon it is not showing data in excel.

When I made some research,I found that Following steps resolved the issue.
1 Right click on icon to view property of file and then click on unblock on property window.
2.Again , when I double click on file it is displaying data.

Can Anyone ,Please help me to fix this issue using ASP.NET and C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

new security settings from office. You can adjust setting in excel to allow downloaded files to be opened. But adjusting this setting is not recommanded because all evil downloaded macro's that you dont know about can run on your pc

1. Open Excel 2013.
2. Click on File > Options.
3. Select Trust Center > Trust center settings.
4. Select Protected view.
5. Uncheck all the options under Protected View > OK.
6. Restart Excel 2010 and try to open Excel documents.

Comment: in this case, every user has to change setting of excel. It will works. Thanks. I am looking for a fix by coding with ASP.NET and C#

Comment: yes that would be ideal. but then you have to trick the pc into believing that the file is not downloaded. perhaps you can export as a CSV file. This does not contains macro's. And can be opened in excel